# Create a percentage bar with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to create a percentage bar with the help of jquery and css.
I am not able to make it work, since jquery css({}) not working.
here are my codes.

*'width' : width - not working for me

```js
//vote percentage
$('.vote-percent').each(function() {
  var percentValue = $(this).find('.percent-num').text();
  $(this).find('.percent-bar').attr('data-percentage', percentValue);
  var width = $(this).find('.percent-bar').attr('data-percentage');
  $(this).find('.percent-bar').css({
    'width': width
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vote-percent flx justify-items-r">
  <span class="percent-num">65%</span>
  <div class="percent-bar"></div>
</div>

<div class="vote-percent flx justify-items-r">
  <span class="percent-num">25%</span>
  <div class="percent-bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="vote-percent flx justify-items-r">
  <span class="percent-num">10%</span>
  <div class="percent-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did some extra steps which I removed from your code, then I added simple styling so you can see the bars.

```js
$('.vote-percent').each(function(){
    var percentValue = $(this).find('.percent-num').text();
    $(this).find('.percent-bar').css('width', percentValue);
});
```

```css
.percent-bar {
    background-color: red;
    height: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vote-percent flx justify-items-r">
    <span class="percent-num">65%</span>
    <div class="percent-bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="vote-percent flx justify-items-r">
    <span class="percent-num">25%</span>
    <div class="percent-bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="vote-percent flx justify-items-r">
    <span class="percent-num">10%</span>
    <div class="percent-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't read from HTML text, use the `data` attribute and read from there.

```js
//vote percentage
$('.vote-percent').each(function() {
  var width = $(this).data('percentage');
  $(this).find('.percent-num').text(width);
  $(this).find('.percent-bar').css({ width });
});
```

```css
.percent-bar {
  background: #3c3f50;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vote-percent flx justify-items-r" data-percentage="65%">
  <span class="percent-num"></span>
  <div class="percent-bar"></div>
</div>

<div class="vote-percent flx justify-items-r" data-percentage="25%">
  <span class="percent-num"></span>
  <div class="percent-bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="vote-percent flx justify-items-r" data-percentage="10%">
  <span class="percent-num"></span>
  <div class="percent-bar"></div>
</div>
```